# Is it possible to log Active Directory users internet activity on a Cisco Firewall-IOS router?

Tags: active-directory, firewall, cisco, ios

We are looking at replacing our Forefront TMG server with a combination Cisco ISE VMware instance and hopefully an Active Directory integration with our edge router. We need to log all authenticated users internet traffic and would like to do it with the router. Is it possible?

Comment: How intrusive does the logging need to be? Cisco devices can log at packet level but I suspect you already know this. Simply append `log` to your firewall rules.

Comment: We only need basic info: source ip, ad username, timestamp, destination ip/web address

Comment: Did you find a soloution? I am also looking to replace a Forefront, and I also need to log my AD users Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We need to log all authenticated users internet traffic and would like
>   to do it with the router. Is it possible?

Yes. You should dig in something like Logging, Inspection, Matching Regex in ASA

Comment: Is this what you are recommending?: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/ibf/setup_guide/ad_agent_setup_guide.html

Comment: Yes, have you tried it?

Comment: No, we currently have a 2821 router with the firewall IOS, so I was hoping to use that. To use this solution it seems like we'll need to purchase an ASA?

Comment: Yes, a router can not manage layer 7 protocol, and I don't know any AD agent for router cisco